# How to load test pure java code?

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests, load-testing

I have written a complex java program and I want to load test it. How can I go about doing this?

I have tried setting up JMeter but it feels like hell: hard to set up and documentation is hard to follow.

What are my available options?

Comment: Depends on the level of testing. If your goal is to measure the performance of application on developer level, i.e. performance of a class, method, etc., look at JMH http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/. But if you are testing on end-user level, JMeter is a right tool, just you need to find the right model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to load test "pure" Java code is using profiling tools, like:

- [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/)
- [Memory Analyzer Tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)
- [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)
- [YourKit Java Profiler](https://www.yourkit.com/download/index.jsp)
- etc.

JMeter does not do any "miracles", it executes tasks in a multithreaded manner and reports time taken - that's it. So theoretically if your application assumes multithreading and heavy operations you can load test individual functions from [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), [JUnit Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter), [Java Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) or even your [custom sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/extending/jmeter_tutorial.pdf)